# Keep getting pop index out of range error

Tags: arrays, loops

```
import random

def eliminate(vote_num):
  random.shuffle(names)
  for p in range(vote_num):
    names.pop(p)
  print(names)


names = []
for x in range(6):
  z = input("Enter a name: ")
  names.append(z)

vote = int(input("How many people would you like to vote off of the island? "))
eliminate(vote)
```

Error states:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 39, in <module>
    eliminate(vote)
  File "main.py", line 20, in eliminate
    names.pop(p)
IndexError: pop index out of range
```

How do I fix this and make it work properly?

The code is supposed to take in 6 names.  After which the user will input a number of names to eliminate.  The function will shuffle the names and eliminate the number of names specified.

Answer (score 0):

Use `pop()` in place of `pop(p)`.